# What's wrong with my jQuery animation syntax?

Tags: jquery, animation, syntax, jquery-animate, appendto

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.title').click(function(){
        $('.nav a li').appendTo.css({bottom:5em);
        $(".nav a li").animate({bottom:$(this).offset().bottom}, slow});
    });
);
```

jQuery newbie here. I need to recreate a banner that has a logo flying in from top, then 8 navigation buttons flying in from top one after another. I started here.

When I click .title, nothing happens. I tried it just on document.ready and nothing happens. Console is blank.

I promise I'll get around to reading my jQuery books... but in the meantime, what am I doing wrong here? I think once I get this right, I can handle everything else in the animation.

Comment: Open the console, you have syntax errors, specifically where you're trying to appendTo a style or whatever that is ?

Answer (score 1):

<s>The animation part is not the problem.</s> *(Actually, it partially is.)* The problem is the line before:

```
$('.nav a li').appendTo.css({bottom:5em);
```

`appendTo` is a function, and `5em` needs to be in quotes. You probably meant:

```
$('.nav a li').appendTo(/*...something here...*/).css({bottom:"5em");
```

Or based on your comment below:

> I'm trying to append bottom:5em to .nav a li's css.

you want just

```
$('.nav a li').css({bottom:"5em");
```

---

What's wrong with the animation part is that `slow` should be in quotes.

Comment: @user2959040: I was just editing based on your comment and something else I noticed. Glad you figured it out.